# SKAction not running after SKScene reloaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm building a game using iOS SpriteKit.  I have a regular `UIViewController` "Chooser" that segues into a second VC that loads a SKScene.  The `SKScene` loads `SKSprites` and moves them via `SKAction` across the screen.  When I run the first round it works great.

After completing a game we return to the `Chooser` to setup the next round.  I reload the same VC with same `SKScene`.  This time the Sprites are created but the `SKAction` does not run.  I added a bunch of logs statements to track it down.

Here's the code with the `SKAction`:

```
NSInteger startZone = [TPMathUtilities randomOffscreenStartZone];
CGPoint startPointONE = [TPMathUtilities OFFScreenPointFinder:startZone];
NSInteger finishZone = [TPMathUtilities finishZoneFinder:startZone];
CGPoint finishPointONE = [TPMathUtilities OFFScreenPointFinder:finishZone];
NSLog(@"startPointONE = %f %f  finishPointONE = %f %f", startPointONE.x,startPointONE.y,finishPointONE.x,finishPointONE.y);
newTap.position = startPointONE;

CGFloat distanceToOffScreenPt = [TPMathUtilities distanceBetweenTwoPoints:startPointONE toPoint:finishPointONE];
CGFloat movementDuration = distanceToOffScreenPt/[[TPGameData data] tapBaseGeneratorVelocity];
NSLog(@"movementDuration = %f", movementDuration);

newTap runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction runBlock:^{NSLog(@"starting TAP ACTIONS ");}],
                                       [SKAction moveTo:finishPointONE duration:movementDuration],
                                       [SKAction removeFromParent]]]];
```

Here's the log for the first round, you can see the "starting TAP ACTIONS"

```
UPDATE variables: localGenMult= 0.800000 tapBaseGen= 0.800000 gameInterval= 0.511158
startPointONE = -50.000000 740.000000  finishPointONE = 913.000000 -50.000000
movementDuration = 4.529381
UPDATE after Sprite Added 
starting TAP ACTIONS 

UPDATE variables: localGenMult= 0.800000 tapBaseGen= 0.800000 gameInterval= 0.512250
startPointONE = 1064.000000 158.000000  finishPointONE = 521.000000 808.000000
movementDuration = 3.079871
UPDATE after Sprite Added 
starting TAP ACTIONS 

UPDATE variables: localGenMult= 0.800000 tapBaseGen= 0.800000 gameInterval= 0.561383
startPointONE = 1064.000000 451.000000  finishPointONE = -50.000000 755.000000
movementDuration = 4.199035
UPDATE after Sprite Added
starting TAP ACTIONS 

UPDATE variables: localGenMult= 0.800000 tapBaseGen= 0.800000 gameInterval= 0.507709
startPointONE = 921.000000 808.000000  finishPointONE = -50.000000 110.000000
movementDuration = 4.348527
UPDATE after Sprite Added 
starting TAP ACTIONS
```

Here's the second round with out the SKAction:

```
UPDATE variables: localGenMult= 0.800000 tapBaseGen= 0.800000 gameInterval= 0.813655
startPointONE = 1064.000000 440.000000  finishPointONE = -50.000000 7.000000
movementDuration = 4.346155
UPDATE after Sprite Added 

UPDATE variables: localGenMult= 0.800000 tapBaseGen= 0.800000 gameInterval= 0.813989
startPointONE = 437.000000 -50.000000  finishPointONE = 652.000000 808.000000
movementDuration = 3.216464
UPDATE after Sprite Added 

UPDATE variables: localGenMult= 0.800000 tapBaseGen= 0.800000 gameInterval= 0.806389
startPointONE = 992.000000 -50.000000  finishPointONE = 856.000000 808.000000
movementDuration = 3.158952
UPDATE after Sprite Added 

UPDATE variables: localGenMult= 0.800000 tapBaseGen= 0.800000 gameInterval= 0.811594
startPointONE = -50.000000 146.000000  finishPointONE = 1064.000000 746.000000
movementDuration = 4.601108
UPDATE after Sprite Added
```

My code for creating the `SKScene` remains the same, and the code above does not change.  Any guess why the action is not activating on the Sprite the second round?

Comment: I think there is a problem with your transition to SKScene not with your actions. You could try testing it  without 'UIViewController'

Comment: What method is that code in?

Comment: @trojanfoe - A custom method used just prior to the Sprite being added to the Scene.

Comment: And you're using view controllers to switch scenes?  If so, I think that is unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DFrog headed me in the right direction.  The problem was in the unwind segue.  My app has an initial VC where players choose a game 'level.'  It segues to a second VC containing the SKScene.  It then 'unwinds' back to the chooserVC at the end of the game.

I deleted all segues/connections between the VC's and made a new unwind segue following the advice here:
[Unwind segue in a nutshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

It now works great.  Thanks all.